# How was the PHP CMS which calls you `extraordinary` after a new installation called?

Tags: php, content-management-system

A few years ago I installed a CMS which was written in PHP. This was a simple CMS like Wordpress. I now want to use it again, but I forgot how it was called. However, the only thing I remember is that, after a new fresh installation, a dummy page said:

> <ADMIN'S NAME> is a .... extraordinare!

(because I used that CMS).

Does someone know how the CMS was called? I thought it was `symfony`, but that seems to be a framework rather than a CMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Symphony is a widely used CMS in PHP see: http://www.getsymphony.com/

I don't know if it used to print out that default message.